# Need help in installing VMKIt ( java front-end for LLVM) ?

Tags: java, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to install VMkit because I need to get LLVM-IR from java bytecode. However , i'm stumped when trying to configure it.  This is what the VMkit website says  : http://vmkit.llvm.org/get_started.html

How should I run this ?  If I copy paste this into terminal I keep getting unknown command errors . Any help would be appreciated.

```
Configure vmkit:
./configure
--with-llvm-config-path=<path/to/llvm-config>
Tell vmkit where the llvm-config binary is located.

--with-mmtk-plan=
org.mmtk.plan.marksweep.MS (default)
org.mmtk.plan.copyms.CopyMS
org.mmtk.plan.semispace.SS
org.mmtk.plan.immix.Immix
org.mmtk.plan.generational.marksweep.GenMS
org.mmtk.plan.generational.copying.GenCopy
org.mmtk.plan.generational.immix.GenImmix
--with-classpath-impl=openjdk
Tell vmkit to use OpenJDK classpath implementation.
```

--with-openjdk-path=
   Tell vmkit where OpenJDK is located.
`

Answer (score 0):

Find your llvm-config:   `which lvvm-config`
Choice your gc: `...generational.marksweep...`
Find your jdk: `readlink -f $(which java)  | sed 's/\/jre\/.*$//'`

Then call your `configure ...`

```
LLVM_CONFIG=$( which lvvm-config )
MMTK_PLAN=org.mmtk.plan.generational.marksweep.GenMS
JAVA_HOME=$( readlink -f "$(which java)" | sed 's/\/jre\/.*$//' )

./configure --with-llvm-config-path="${LLVM_CONFIG}" --with-mmtk-plan="${MMTK_PLAN}" --with-classpath-impl="openjdk" --with-openjdk-path="${JAVA_HOME}"
```